# A good way to temporarily store data for multiple views in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a main view controller that contains a variable amount of buttons (usually 6). When one of those buttons is tapped, I query a server to fetch a stream of information with roughly 40 items, and then I pop that data into a tableview. The stream is analogous to a Twitter stream, and so I can't keep the data on the device since it's always changing.

I can always expect a delay when pressing a button that I haven't pressed before cause the data has never been loaded onto the device. I want to know how I should temporarily store that data. That way I can immediately load the tableview the second time I press the button (from the main view) while the new data is loading.

Let me know if I'm being too abstract.

Comment: Do you mean for the data to be persistent? So if the app closes and reopens, the old data will be there until new data arrives?

Comment: Yes, I do. That's part of the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a nsarray property of your vc and use that array as your tableview datasource

Comment: Ha, I feel a dumb now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure where I was thinking I should go, but you gave me the right direction. I used a mutable dictionary instead of an array so I can add the data on the fly, and I'm just using the unique IDs I have attached to each stream. It seems to be working wonderfully. Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to get into Core Data, I'd say try to serialize out your data into a flat file. Then using NSFileManager, store this file in the application Cache directory. Then when the application launches again, read in from this file before requesting from the network.

Augie's answer to pass this data between view controllers is the way to go during the lifetime of the app. This Cache file would only be necessary when the application terminates and re-launches.

Comment: If you've never heard of Core Data, thats the way to go.

Comment: Ya, I adopted a version of Augie's answer, but I'll have to do this later to add persistency.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use an NSArray property , but if you also want the data to be persistent after a relaunch of the app, I would advise you to use CoreData.